# Snakeyaml: Cannot create property for

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I've a yaml fileto be passed as an argument to the java class. But it throws below exception:

Logs

```
Caused by: Cannot create property=heartbeatThreshold for JavaBean=UdsConfigurationBean{jdbcDriverClassString='org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver', sparkConfigFile='spark/spark-local.conf'}
 in 'reader', line 15, column 3:
      jdbcDriverClassString: org.maria ... 
      ^
Unable to find property 'heartbeatThreshold' on class: MyClass
 in 'reader', line 36, column 23:
      heartbeatThreshold: 60000000
                          ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:292)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:171)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObjectNoCheck(BaseConstructor.java:230)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:219)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:269)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'heartbeatThreshold' on class: MyClass
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:159)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:309)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:230)
    ... 16 more
```

My Analysis:

1. MyClass is packaged as jar and it works for another project,so there should be problem with my yaml file.
2. Yaml validations has passed and seems all the variables are using camelCase.
3. As per my findings, PropertyUtils has 2 checks for this exception to be thrown, if property value is null(which it is not as per logs) and isWritable(I didn't get this part)
4. for jdbcDriverClassString, error indication is at name and for heartbeatThreshold value, its at value.

Can you please help me figure it out. I would be really grateful.

Yaml file:

```
kafka:
  kafkaServers: ${udsKafkaEpfConfigurationBean.kafka.kafkaServers}
  kafkaPrincipal: ${udsKafkaEpfConfigurationBean.kafka.kafkaPrincipal}
  kafkaKeytab: ${udsKafkaEpfConfigurationBean.kafka.kafkaKeytab}
  kafkaEnvironment: ${udsKafkaEpfConfigurationBean.kafka.kafkaEnvironment}
  

storage:
  jdbcDriverClassString: ${memsql.driver}   
  initializationStoresGeneration: true
  heartbeatThreshold: ${MyCLass.kafka.heartbeatThreshold}
```

Comment: Maybe in your other project, class `MyClass` actually has a property named `heartbeatThreshold`?

Comment: Sorry my bad I meant, there is a MyClass which is packaged as a jar and both the projects are hitting the jar. When I'm trying to hit it using this yaml, I'm facing issues while its working fine for the other one.

Comment: You sure you don't have two difference `MyClass` classes on the classpath?

Comment: yes, I'm sure there is no other MyClass class.

Comment: Please describe how it *works for another project*: Are you using that identical YAML file in the other project? If not, please show the file you're using. Also please show the relevant source of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, add *Skip Missing Properties* property to the yaml fixes the problem:

```
Yaml = new Yaml()
```

change to

```
Representer represent = new Representer()
represent.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true)
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(represent)
```